# GL version of GLsurfaceview

Tags: android, opengl-es

I need GLSurfaceView to render something, here is something that make me confusing:
I call the setEGLContextClientVersion(2) at first, but in the onSurfaceCreated(), I call the gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST), only to get a glError, as follow:

here is the code:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);

    gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glGenTextures(1, mTextureNameWorkspace, 0);

    int textureName = mTextureNameWorkspace[0];
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE);

    final int internalFormat = GL10.GL_RGBA;
    final int type = GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE;
    gl.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, mCameraPreviewSprite.textureWidth, mCameraPreviewSprite.textureHeight, 0, internalFormat, type, (ByteBuffer) null);

    mCameraPreviewSprite.setTextureName(textureName);
}
```

here are the error messages:

```
E/MALI(22964): gles_state_set_error_internal:57: GLES error code:0x500
E/MeizuSource_Algo_Af(239): DEBUG: gyroinform(0, 0, 0)
E/AndroidRuntime(22964): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1335
E/AndroidRuntime(22964): Process: de.renard.glcamera, PID: 22964
E/AndroidRuntime(22964): android.opengl.GLException: invalid enum
E/AndroidRuntime(22964):    at          android.opengl.GLErrorWrapper.checkError(GLErrorWrapper.java:62)
E/AndroidRuntime(22964):    at android.opengl.GLErrorWrapper.glHint(GLErrorWrapper.java:387)
E/AndroidRuntime(22964):    at de.renard.glcamera.CameraPreviewRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(CameraPreviewRenderer.java:75)
E/AndroidRuntime(22964):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1547)
E/AndroidRuntime(22964):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1285)
```

however, other similar errors of the following gl call occur when I delete the glHint, is that caused by the version of gl es version? Thank you!

Here is the code in the `onCreate()` function in the Activity:

```
if(supportsEs2)
   mGlSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
mGlSurfaceView.setRenderer(mRenderer); 
mGlSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY); 
mGlSurfaceView.setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR); 
setContentView(mGlSurfaceView);
```

Comment: Please post the code where you call setEGLContextClientVersion(). The GL context may already be in an error state when entering onSurfaceCreated. Also make sure you have <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" /> in your manifest

Comment: the glEsVersion="0x00020000" tag was already there, and here is the code in the onCreate() function in the Activity:
 '  
if(supportsEs2)
   mGlSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
  mGlSurfaceView.setRenderer(mRenderer);
  mGlSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
  mGlSurfaceView.setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR);
  setContentView(mGlSurfaceView);'

Comment: Did you get any solution?